# multiple MySQL queries vs. multiple PHP Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I originally had a page that ran 60 MySQL queries, which was obviously flawed.  The page took a couple seconds to load.  So i changed the code to one MySQL query and used php sessions/arrays to arrange the 60 results.  The page now loads much faster/instantly but I'm wondering is this way better than the MySQL, design wise?  I have an incrementing session that is set in a while loop(60 loops), each session holds an array, which i then sort.

Comment: Having 60 queries isn't wise, using sessions to handle it surelly ain't as well.

Comment: "Is this way better than the mysql, performance wise?"  No, you stated that the page loads faster with one query.  What are you really asking?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of copy-paste. Can you gather all the results and sort them in 1 query?

Comment: using `$_SESSION` to store queries?! Let's see some code and we'll be able to advise you better.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some code.

Comment: design wise, how would you handle it?  If not multiple queries or multiple sessions what is the best alternative for performance?

Comment: Consolidating database queries is almost always a good thing, but I really don't see what "mysql query" has to do with "php session".  The two things aren't remotely like one another, and you certainly can't replace one with the other.  The "incrementing session" and "60 loops" that you describe makes no sense to me, but sounds like something that is probably not being done correctly.

Comment: Going to dogpile on and agree that the description of what is being done doesn't match my understanding of how these mechanics function. It sounds like what he means by "multiple sessions" is multiple session variables.  Session variables aren't a substitute for mysql queries.  For select statements, often the solution is to cache the result in memory using memcached or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

both are bad as yoda did say

you have to move in completely different direction:

1. *Sensibly* reduce number of queries. There is nothing actually bad in having 60 queries, and a page could have it and still load in a fraction of second. But it would be wise to remove unnecessary ones.
2. Optimize query runtime. Determine which query runs slow and optimize it, by using `DESC query` query (or rather `explain extended`+`show warnings`), using indexes and such

It's impossible to say more for such a vague question with not a single query for example

Comment: With mysql, I think it's best to recommend the use of explain extended, rather than desc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce number of queries.
2. Optimize queries for performance.
3. Use memcache or APC if instead of session. Sessions are not made for this purpose.